# Share a USB HDD between Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the free space of an external USB disk on which I have an NTFS partition with data. At first I had no problems; but at some point I was able to access the partition from Ubuntu but not from Windows. Also, I don't see the external disk from Windows. The disc works. In fact I can keep booting Ubuntu from it and see all its content. How can I recover NTFS partition on Windows?
Thanks in advance an best regards.
José

Comment: Please show us `sudo fdisk --list` and put the output ito your question.

Answer (score 0):

so what format have you used for your Ubuntu partition, because usually windows does not have the ability to read Linux specific drive partitions, but Linux can read both types.
if my understanding of your phrasing is correct, your windows partition no longer boots?
Firstly check Grub, windows somehow messes it up sometimes, I have had that issue.

if it does and if you go to disk manager I suppose you will be able to see that space allocated. If in case your windows partition is not working, boot into Ubuntu, preferably Ubuntu live and copy the contents from windows to your Ubuntu partition. Repair or reinstall Windows. Copy files back being booted into Ubuntu.

Also, Disable fast boot in Windows and i do not know if hibernating windows is a good idea, i have had some issues in the past.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 2 disks. One internal with Windows 10 and the external USB drive I can't see from Windows.

Comment: look at how it is partitioned, if its ext2 or something similar it usually, to my knowledge, can't be opened in windows. if you never had a problem and didnt change the partition or reinstall, i dont see why windows would do that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll continue investigating.